# Neo4j spring data NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-neo4j

I am using `Neo4j` with `Spring-boot`. I am getting the following error while trying to run my test class:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationSource.getAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/Optional;
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.config.Neo4jRepositoryConfigurationExtension.postProcess(Neo4jRepositoryConfigurationExtension.java:110) ~[spring-data-neo4j-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:127) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:83) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.
```

**Pom.xlm**

```
<groupId>com.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>my_app</name>
    <description>my app desc</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.swagger/swagger-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Mysql dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- JPA dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**NodeTest.java: **

```
/**
 * 
 * @author Prakash Pandey 11-Dec-2017
 *
 */
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Neo4jConfiguration.class)
public class NodeTest {

    @Autowired
    private NodeRepository nodeRepository;
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NodeTest.class);

    @Test
    public void createNodes() {
        log.debug("==================== Inside createNodes ======================");

        MyNodes myNodes = new MyNodes();
        myNodes.setUserId(1000L);
        myNodes.setName("Prakash Pandey");
        myNodes.setOrganisation(Organisations.HDFC.getValue());
        myNodes.setCreationDate(new Date());
        myNodes.setLastUpdatedOn(new Date());
        myNodes.setParent(null);
        myNodes.save(zhrNodes);

        log.debug("==================== Outside createNodes ======================");
    }
}
```

**MyNodes.java: **

```
@NodeEntity
public class MyNodes {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Long userId;
    private String name;
    private String organisation;
    private Date creationDate;
    private Date lastUpdatedOn;

    @Relationship(type = Edges.CHILD, direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    private MyNodes parent;

    public MyNodes getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(MyNodes parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOrganisation() {
        return organisation;
    }

    public void setOrganisation(String organisation) {
        this.organisation = organisation;
    }

    public Date getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedOn() {
        return lastUpdatedOn;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedOn(Date lastUpdatedOn) {
        this.lastUpdatedOn = lastUpdatedOn;
    }


}
```

**NodeRepository.java:**

```
public interface NodeRepository extends Neo4jRepository<MyNodes, Long> {

}
```

**Neo4jConfiguration.java:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.graph")
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.graph")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        // with domain entity base package(s)
        return new SessionFactory(configuration(), "com.graph");
    }

    @Bean
    public org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration() {
        org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration configuration = new org.neo4j.ogm.config.Configuration();
        configuration.driverConfiguration().setURI("bolt://localhost").setCredentials("neo4j", "neo4j");
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:**

As suggested by `Nelson Christos` in his answer, when using the below dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**I am getting error:**

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not load driver: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:57) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.DriverService.load(DriverService.java:69) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.loadDriver(Components.java:158) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.service.Components.driver(Components.java:104) ~[neo4j-ogm-api-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:44) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:93) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at com.hdfc.hierarchymanagement.graph.Neo4jConfiguration.sessionFactory(Neo4jConfiguration.java:24) ~[test-classes/:na]
    at com.hdfc.hierarchymanagement.graph.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a58db7d.CGLIB$sessionFactory$0(<generated>) ~[test-classes/:na]
    at com.hdfc.hierarchymanagement.graph.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a58db7d$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$9ef0ff91.invoke(<generated>) ~[test-classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:358) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.hdfc.hierarchymanagement.graph.Neo4jConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a58db7d.sessionFactory(<generated>) ~[test-classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

**Edit 2 :**

As suggested by **Synch in his answer below, ** updating full stack-trace here:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.newTransaction(Lorg/neo4j/ogm/transaction/Transaction$Type;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/ogm/transaction/Transaction;
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:71) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:57) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.TransactionsDelegate.beginTransaction(TransactionsDelegate.java:36) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.beginTransaction(Neo4jSession.java:463) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.5.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doBegin(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:176) ~[spring-data-neo4j-4.2.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 25 common frames omitted    


org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Neo4j Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.newTransaction(Lorg/neo4j/ogm/transaction/Transaction$Type;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/ogm/transaction/Transaction;
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.transaction.Neo4jTransactionManager.doBegin(Neo4jTransactionManager.java:199)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:461)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy78.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.hdfc.hierarchymanagement.graph.NodeTest.createNodes(NodeTest.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Spring Data NEO 4j 5 requires Spring 5. You are using a Spring Boot version that uses Spring 4. Use the `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` instead of directly a dependency on the project to get a compatible version.

Comment: @M.Deinum I first used `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` but got `Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not load driver: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.`. I request you to please have a look at my `edit 1`

Comment: You still need to specify one of the drivers you want to use (the default if none detected is the `BoltDriver`).

Comment: how to do that. I mean which driver to use. which driver is compatible with spring

Comment: The stacktrace already gives you that answer, the jar including the `BoltDriver` class...

Comment: @M.DeinumThanks. I successfully solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring automatically manages the versions of its dependencies to avoid compatibility issues. Unless you know what you are doing, it is ill-advised to manually set a version to override this functionality.

You are also missing a driver dependency for Spring Data Neo4j to use. By default, it uses the `BoltDriver`. If you indeed wish to use this driver, include it in your `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.neo4j/neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
    <version>${neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are using Spring 4, use version `2.1.5` for the bolt driver.
If you are using Spring 5, use version `3.0.2` for the bolt driver.

Comment: did as you said

Comment: got error `org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Neo4j Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.newTransaction(Lorg/neo4j/ogm/transaction/Transaction$Type;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/ogm/transaction/Transaction;`

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.newTransaction(Lorg/neo4j/ogm/transaction/Transaction$Type;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/neo4j/ogm/transaction/Transaction;
 at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:71)
 at org.neo4j.ogm.session.transaction.DefaultTransactionManager.openTransaction(DefaultTransactionManager.java:57)`

Comment: Could update your question with the complete stacktrace?

Comment: Also, can you update which version of Spring you are going to use?

Comment: please suggest which version i should go with

Comment: I tried with neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver : 2.1.5. It worked. Should I use v2.1.5. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a versioning issue. Can you try the below dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: First I used this but got error `Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.ServiceNotFoundException: Could not load driver: org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.driver.BoltDriver.`. 

I am posting Full stack-trace (when using dependency as you said above) in my edit 1. Please have a look

Comment: Please have a look, I have added full stack-trace in my question section edit 1.

Comment: You will need to include the driver dependencies as well

Answer (score 1):

`spring-boot:1.5.9.RELEASE` depends on Spring 4.

`spring-data-neo4j:5.0.2.RELEASE` depends on Spring 5.

You have to either downgrade the neo4j dependency to `4.x.x` or upgrade spring-boot to `2.x.x`.

Comment: I am writing an application to put it in production in 2 weeks. Please suggest if spring-boot 2.x.x is stable

Comment: Spring Boot 2.x is currently in its milestone phase, so it is not guaranteed to be stable.

Comment: I agree with Synch. So if you need to release so soon you probably can't combine the latest `spring-data-neo4j` with `spring-boot`. Isn't `spring-boot-starter-data-neo4j` bringing version `4.x.x` of this dependency? Nelson Christos' answer sounds correct to me.

Comment: These are the jar I found in my `maven dependencies`: spring-data-neo4j-`4.2.9.RELEASE.jar,    neo4j-ogm-core-2.1.5.jar,    neo4j-ogm-compiler-2.1.5.jar,  neo4j-ogm-http-driver-2.1.5.jar,  neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.0.2.jar,    neo4j-ogm-api-2.1.5.jar, neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar`

Comment: bot driver used : `<groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.2</version>`